# How to prevent vertical drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do a table with dragging events. I want to prevent vertical dragging; how can I make it possible?

Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5VXDt/1/). I'm trying to drag only one row at a time, and need to prevent vertical drag.

Please update the fiddle.

```
function rangeMouseMove(e) {
  if (isDragging) {
    var allCells = $("#table td");
    dragEnd = allCells.index($(this));
    selectRange();
  }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If u wanna go for hammer.js..then it'll help u:

To improve the user experience while doing a gesture, you should prevent the browser from scrolling. This can be done with the ev.gesture.preventDefault() method. For vertical swiping, dragging should be prevented, or it wont work (in most cases..)

For the best overall experience, you can set the preventDefault option to true. This gives Hammer the full control over the touch input on the given element. But it disables all default browser actions.

**Horizontal swipe and drag** :

```
var options = {
  dragLockToAxis: true,
  dragBlockHorizontal: true
};
var hammertime = new Hammer(element, options);
hammertime.on("dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight", function(ev){ });
```

**Transform (pinch, rotate):**

```
var options = {
  preventDefault: true
};
var hammertime = new Hammer(element, options);
hammertime.on("transform", function(ev){ });
```

**Vertical swipe and drag:**

Because vertical movements are very tricky on devices, people intent to scroll, you should try to avoid these. If you do want them, the best way to configure Hammer is just to prevent the defaults.

```
var options = {
  preventDefault: true
};
var hammertime = new Hammer(element, options);
hammertime.on("dragup dragdown swipeup swipedown", function(ev){ });
```

One hammer can rule them all..hope it helps..!

Answer (score 0):

Will you consider libs like Hammer.js?

About your question, you can have a FIFO array. Drag events in from left, out from right. Only horizontal drag events are allowed in.

```
// pseudo code
var q = [];

$t.on('drag', function (e) {
  if (e.direction === 'left' || e.direction === 'right') {
    q.push(e.deltaX);
  }
});

setTimeinterval(function () {
  if (q.length) {
     _apply(q.shift());
  }
}, 100);
```